# Update/renew countdown frame whenever it is raised by tkraise() in tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I am trying to create a 2 mins countdown app with multiple windows. I am putting all windows(frames) into the main container, and then use tkraise() to raise the frame whenever the navigation button to specific window is clicked(eg:'startPage' frame will be raised if 'back to startPage' button is clicked). 
The code below works well only when the object of class PracticePage was first created.
However, the timer is still running at the back when I navigate from the countdown timer frame(class PracticePage) to another page. In other words,  the timer will not count down from 2 mins whenever I navigate from another page back to the countdown timer page. I want it to countdown from 2 mins whenever the timer frame is raised.
I am a beginner in programming. I apologized if my question and code is confusing. Can someone help? Thank you in advance.

Below is my code:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
import time

class App(tk.Tk):   #we want this class to inherit from tk.Tk
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):  
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        tk.Tk.wm_title(self,"PreSys")

        container = tk.Frame(self, height = 1000, width =1000)
        container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand = True)

        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        self.frames = {}

        for F in (SignInPage, StartPage, PracticePage):

            frame = F(container, self)

            self.frames[F] = frame

            frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")

        self.show_frame(SignInPage)

    def show_frame(self, cont):
        frame = self.frames[cont]
        frame.tkraise()   #to raise one of the frames up to the front    


class StartPage(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)


        self.startButton = ttk.Button(self, text="スタート", command = lambda: controller.show_frame(PracticePage))

        self.startButton.pack()

class PracticePage(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.timeLeft = tk.Label(self,text= "")
        self.backButton = ttk.Button(self, text="やり直す", command = lambda: controller.show_frame(StartPage))
        self.homeButton = ttk.Button(self, text="サインアウト", command = lambda: controller.show_frame(SignInPage))

        self.timeLeft.pack()
        self.backButton.pack()
        self.homeButton.pack()
        #rc.start_record(SignInPage.entry_name.get())

        self.remaining = 0
        self.countdown(121)

    def countdown(self, remaining = None):
        if remaining is not None:
            self.remaining = remaining

        if self.remaining <= 0:
            self.timeLeft.configure(text="お疲れ様です！")
        else:
            mins, secs = divmod(self.remaining,60)
            mins = round(mins)
            secs = round(secs)
            self.timeLeft.configure(text=str(mins) +"分"+ str(secs) +"秒")
            self.remaining = self.remaining - 1
            self.after(1000, self.countdown)

apps = App()
apps.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before we get to the solution, when you supply your code make sure it works. You removed the `SignInPage` because it wasn't necessary, but you didn't follow up and remove the other references to it (i.e.- `self.show_frame(SignInPage)` in `App.__init__` and `self.homebutton` in `PracticePage`.

As for your issue with resetting the timer, there are many ways to go about it, but they all come down to the fact that all you are doing is raising frames: you don't include any code that influences `countdown` based on what frame you are currently switching to.

Since this is a relatively simple application, I'll suggest the simplest solution: when you raise `PracticePage` reset its `remaining` variable. To keep it as easy and consistent as possible, we'll just modify `show_frame`

```
## You should store variables that are meaningful (you can place this underneath the imports)
PRACTICETIME = 121

## App():
    def show_frame(self, cont):
        frame = self.frames[cont]
        if cont == PracticePage:
            frame.remaining = PRACTICETIME
        frame.tkraise()   #to raise one of the frames up to the front
```

In a larger application I would recommend either using `widget.after_cancel()` to stop the countdown completely or simply to destroy and recreate your `Pages` if reasonable to do so. With this method you may notice a 1-second lag where the PracticePage is still displaying the previous `remaining` time: if this really bothers you, then I would recommend extracting the code that formats `PracticePage.timeLeft` into its own function and then calling that function from `App.show_frame` right after you set `remaining`.

Comment: Thank You for your reply and recommendations. I did according to your recommendation of extracting `PracticePage.timeLeft` into own function and called that from `App.show_frame`. It really works! But I don't understand why it won't work if I put the function in class PracticePage right before I call `self.countdown(122)` ?

Comment: When you say you're putting the function right before `self.countdown(122)` do you mean that you are defining it (writing `def updatetimeLeft():`) inside of `PracticePage.__init__` before the last line that says `self.countdown(121)`?

Comment: Also, typing `self.countdown(122)` in the comment here instead of `self.countdown(121)` which is in your code illustrates why you should be using variables for these kinds of things. If you wanted to change the starting countdown time you could easily do so by just changing a variable (in my example, `PRACTICETIME`) instead of having to go back through the code updating it everywhere and hoping you found them all and didn't make a mistake on any o them.

Comment: I'm guessing at this point that you've moved on with your app. If you're satisfied with this answer, feel free to click the checkmark to the left to accept it. If there was anything else, just let me know.